# Getting an error and warning when running webpack command in terminal. "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bundle.js'"

Tags: webpack

I'm a beginner with webpack and am coding along in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lziuNMk_8eQ&t=560s

I had an issue with one of the first steps. I installed webpack via "npm init" in my project directory. Then I created an index.html and an app.js. Then I type in this command (where I'm getting the error):

```
webpack app.js bundle.js
```

This is the error message and warning I get:

```
Hash: bdfaf7d26353121c4df4
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 122ms
Built at: 3/12/2018 9:14:55 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
   [0] ./app.js 23 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] multi ./app.js bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment. 

ERROR in multi ./app.js bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bundle.js' in '/Users/toads/dev/leetcode-solutions'
 @ multi ./app.js bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `webpack --mode development` or `webpack --mode production`